# Resources needed: Sort 2D array "graphically"

Tags: language-agnostic

I have a 2D array

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9

and want to sort it like this

Snake

1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5

Snake (different)

1 2 3
6 5 4
7 8 9

Rotated

1 4 7
2 5 8
3 6 9

Wipe (diagonal)

1 3 6
2 5 8
4 7 9

Well, you got it, all kinds of sorting.

Searching the interweb for hours now. Any resources (specific language or pseudo code) on that greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Suggestion: Dump all values in a 1D-array and sort there. Then define the patterns for filling using multiple for loops.

Comment: Why not? However, any resources for sorting the array then?

Comment: You mean 1D sort? -> Arrays.sort()