# Formula needed: Sort array to array-"zig-zag"

Tags: arrays, language-agnostic, sorting

I have the following array:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
```

I use it for some visual stuff like this:

```
1   2  3  4

5   6  7  8

9  10 11 12

13 14 15 16
```

Now I want to sort the array like this to have a "zig-zag" when rendering later.

```
// rearrange the array according to this schema
1  3  6 10

2  5  9 13

4  8 12 15

7 11 14 16

// the original array should look like this:

a = [1,5,2,9,6,3,13,10,7,4,14,11,8,15,12,16]
// the second index to draw should be the first index in the second row,
// which is represent by 5 in the original 1D Array
```

Yeah, now I'm looking for a smart formula to do that

```
ticker = 0;
rows = 4; // can be n
cols = 4; // can be n
originalArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16];
newArray = [];

while(ticker < originalArray.length)
{
    //do the magic here
    ticker++;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your examples are correct ? In the second case the flattened array does not match the 2D representation.

Comment: The hint is in his example. He wants to arrange the numbers into something like a standing rhomboid with 1 at the top, then tilted 45° to the left.

Comment: I realized the zig-zag much later, I was too taken in by the `sort`-word. This really is a permutation.

Comment: More input needed here. Will your array always have a fixed size? Or can we at least assume it will always be square (i.e. nRows = nCols)?

Comment: Thanks Carl, thats what i meant to do.

I use ActionScript, but any pseudo code is welcome...

Comment: Yeah, I missed something like

rows = 4
cols = 4

before the while loop

Comment: I still don't see an answer to my two questions!

Comment: Ohh, now I got it. No, rows not necessarily equals cols. Sorry for this back and forth...

Comment: Then it's not always a square :) OK, so this permuting method will receive the array and also a row and column count as arguments.

Comment: Why is the flattened array `a = [1,5,2,9,6,3,13,10,7,4,14,11,8,15,12,16]` ? Why isn't it `a = [1,3,6,10,2,5,9,13,4,8,12,15,7,11,14,16]`, to match the 2D representation ?

Comment: Possible duplicate (same poster) yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453368

Comment: @Paul

1. Because I'm drawing the array row-wise
2. Yes, that was me...

Comment: @Paul However, that also might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave it sorted in the original order, you just have to step through it differently.  **EDIT**: Turns out that my naive implementation didn't account for the differing step size based on the diagonal.  The code below does and has been tested in C#.

```
 var diagonals = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
 for (int i = 0, m = 0; m < 4; i = i + m, ++m) {
     for (int j = m, k = 0; k < 4; j = j + diagonals[m+k+1], ++k) {
          Console.Write( i+j+1  );
          Console.Write( " " );
     }
    Console.WriteLine();
 }
```

Obviously, you could use this algorithm to fill a new array if you needed to keep that ordering around.  It should also scale -- you just need to change the termination conditions to the square root of the array size and automate the generation of the diagonals.

Comment: When I run this loop and push the original array values to a new array I get this:

newArray = [1,3,6,10,3,5,8,12,7,9,12,16,13,15,,]

Comment: @aw - I've fixed this to account for the differing diagonal lengths and to adjust the order in which the increments happen.  This has been tested.

Comment: Now I'm getting this [1,3,6,10,3,6,10,14,6,10,14,,10,14,,]. But you said it's tested, right?

Comment: @aw -- transcription error. This time I just pasted the code from Snippet Compiler into the question so it should work. You'll have to translate from C#. Note that I'm just writing out the index+1 (basically the contents of your array). You should use `array[i+j]` instead.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks!

How the I have to change the diagonals array if I have, let's say 7 rows and 9 cols?

Comment: Also, it would be cool, to have the matrix mirrored horizontally. So that the rendering starts on the right side...

Comment: @aw -- I'll leave that as an exercise for you.  It shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

Comment: Well, the scaling to n rows/cols was indeed no problem. However, my head spins around from trying to flip this hole thing horizontally. Not sure, if I can solve the loop to that...

Comment: Instead of just writing them out, push the numbers onto a stack, then at the end of the inner loop, pop them all from the stack and put them where they belong.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the structure of your matrix:

```
1    3
|  / /
| / / 
|/ /  ...
2 /  5 
 / /    
/ /
4
```

The 1st row starts at 1

The 2nd row starts at 2 = 1 + 1 (# elements in 1st zig)

The 3rd row starts at 4 = 1 
                          + 1 (# elements in 1st zig)
                          + 2 (# elements in 2nd zig)

...

The 3rd row ends at 6 = start of 3rd row + row num
                      = 4 + 3 = 7

You can derive a closed form formula for the `i`th row and go ahead.